# How to update data from localhost mysql to remote mysql server?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, remote-access

I have local_db which is stored on localhost. T1 is the table in local_db.
I just want to insert the data of T1 to T2. T2 is the table in remote_db which is stored on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [14.9. The FEDERATED Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-storage-engine.html)